# Error in formatting js and css

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, slider

I have a slide that I call through a static block

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('slider_cartao')->toHtml(); ?>
```

in the `inline.phtml` file. It is displayed as follows:

[image]

And inspecting the code with the slider in this place to get an idea, it looks like this:

[image]

However I had to change this file slider, calling it the same way, but only now in the onestep.phtml file and it is displayed as follows totally unformatted none:

[image]

And inspecting the code with the slider already changed to the file `onestep.phtml` to get an idea, it looks like this:

[image]

With these examples you can get an idea of how the difference is even in the `div's` that contains the slider.

**I do not know why this is happening because `js` and `css` are already loaded at the top of the page and I just changed the block slider, I did not change any code contained in the files. All help will be very good life.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is blurry, what file have you changed ? thiscms block `slider_cartao` ?

Comment: @Prince I have changed only the file / location of which I call the static block that contains the slider. Before I called this static block in the `inline.phtml` file, however I changed it by calling the static block in the `onestep.phtml` file. In the `slider_cartao` CMS block, I have not made changes to make this problem happen.

Comment: Check your CSS and JS files are calling in the onestepcheckout page by viewing source code option in browser. Also check for java script conflicts in the console.log

Comment: @Matheus Portela check your css classes in `onestep.phtml` maybe you have the same classes id etc.. who maybe replace slider_cartao properties

Comment: This is really tricky. It could be many things. Is onestep.phtml part of the checkout process?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis Yes, the onestep.phtml file looks like the main file that contains the other blocks that make up the page.

Comment: @Prince So I do not understand why this is happening. All js and css files are loaded when I look at the source code in the browser and there is no error on the console either. I just changed the location of what I call the static block. Before it was inside the file inline.phtml which is a block that is "inside" the file onestep.phtml and everything works right, doing only the change of "place", calling the same block directly inside the file onestep.phtml, it stays totally unformatted css and js functionality.

Comment: @duke The above comment is explanation for you too.

Comment: The default magento 'onepage' system uses json and s notorious for "killing" js in any phtml loaded by json. I think this is your problem. onestep.phtml is loaded by json so the js is not triggered

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis I updated the issue with some additional information.

Comment: In the right pane of the developers tools you can see that  owl.carousel.min.css is NOT loaded for this page or json page part

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis And even though I adding the css "in hand" in the local.xml with the following code , it still does not load the same.

Comment: `<onestepcheckout_index_index><reference name="head"><action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/carousel/script.js</name><params/></action><action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/carousel/carouselStyle.css</stylesheet><params/></action><action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/carousel/owl.carousel.min.css</stylesheet><params/></action><action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css</stylesheet><params/></action></reference></onestepcheckout_index_index>`

Comment: I would like to point one thing, may be you are not initializing the carousal. I encountered this issue many times. You have to get the initialization javacript in this page too.

Comment: Yes, this being the error, the lack of js and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much inspect codes, I saw that the error is in the lack of loading of `js` and `css` so that the carousel is mounted. It turned out that for my case, I put an upper `border` to be able to separate the blocks of the magento.